# Можно ли перегенерировать java-бины из wsdl-схемы?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wsdl

Возможно ли перегенерировать java-бины из wsdl-схемы? Например, если я уже сгенерировала java-бины из wsdl-схемы, и после этого эта схема немного изменилась, могу ли я перегенерировать java-бины, вместо того, чтобы удалять уже созданные java-бины и генерировать новые?